# put loader on viewRender call remove it after eventRender completed in fullCalender

Tags: php, fullcalendar

i am using fullCalender and i want to add loader on fullCalender's header button gets click, header part is in image.
[image]

so, i put loader on viewRender function and remove it on eventRender function like,

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element.find(".fc-event-title").remove();
      var new_description = '';
      new_description = '<strong>'+ event.start_time +' - '+ event.end_time +'</strong><br/>'
          +'<strong>Name : </strong>' + event.display_name + '<br/>'
          + '<strong>Branch : </strong>' + event.customer_branch + '<br/>'
          + '<strong>Event by: </strong>' + event.event_by + '<br/>'
          + '<strong>Show as: </strong>' + event.show_as + '<br/>'
          + '<strong>Date:</strong>' + event.date + '<br/>';
      element.append(new_description);
      $(".loader").fadeOut();
},
viewRender: function(view, element){
      $(".loader").fadeIn();
},
```

it is working all right for most cases but when i click on week button(right most in image). it will only fade in loader, it will not fade out loader. please help me with this bug or give me if it has other method to do this in fullCalender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many events have you got? Fading out the loader every time you render an event is repetitive and inefficient if you have more than one event visible. Also what if there are no events in the current date range? Then it will never fade out - this may be the cause of your issue.

You should use "eventAfterAllRender" for this instead. It will always run once, even if there are no events in the current date range.

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {
  $(".loader").fadeOut();
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/611/ for a minimalist demonstration.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventAfterAllRender for documentation.

Comment: thank you,that's working perfectly. i added this and remove fade out from eventRender.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. P.S. I just noticed there is also this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/loading if you are using ajax requests to fetch your events, it provides a more built-in way to display a loader. e.g. I think it would trigger even if you just ran "refetchEvents" without changing the current view, whereas "viewRender" would not run in that situation to trigger the loader.